# Get the most derived type from std::type_index for component

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, typeid

I have the following code that allows me to use an entity component system. However, due to the nature of templates, adding components from a `std::vector<HE2_Component*>` causes them to be added with the typeID of `HE2_Component` instead of their most derived form (example at bottom of code). How can I force this to correctly identify component types?

```
template<typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<HE2_Component, T>>>
    void addComponent(T* component)
{
    components.insert(std::make_pair(std::type_index(typeid(T)), component));
    component->host = this;
}


template<typename CompType,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<HE2_Component, CompType>>>
    inline void removeComponent()
{
    auto it = components.find(std::type_index(typeid(CompType)));

    if (it == components.end())
        return;

    components.erase(it->first);
}


template<typename CompType,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<HE2_Component, CompType>>>
    inline CompType* getComponent()
{
    auto it = components.find(std::type_index(typeid(CompType)));

    if (it == components.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Object does not contain this component!");
        return nullptr;
    }


    return dynamic_cast<CompType*>(it->second);
}


//EXAMPLE HERE 
//Setup
HE2_ComponentOwner* obj = new HE2_ComponentOwner();
HE2_ComponentOwner* obj2 = new HE2_ComponentOwner();

class A : virtual public HE2_Component { double f = 0.0; };
class B : virtual public HE2_Component { float b = 0.0f; };
class C : public HE2_Component { int x = 0; };

//Add some components from a vector to obj
std::vector<HE2_Component*> comps = { new A(), new B(), new C() };
for (auto x : comps)
    obj->addComponent(x);

//Add some manually to obj2
obj2->addComponent(new A());
obj2->addComponent(new B());
obj2->addComponent(new C());

//This doesn't work
A* a = obj->getComponent<A>();
B* a = obj->getComponent<B>();
C* c = obj->getComponent<C>();

//This does work

A* a = obj2->getComponent<A>();
B* b = obj2->getComponent<B>();
C* c = obj2->getComponent<C>();
```

Comment: you need to do `typeid(*component)` to get the dynamic type of the object, not the declared typename. naturally, `typeid(T)` will always be `T`. so, if you pass a less-derived class, and that's your `T`, `typeid(T)` is not equivalent to `typeid(*component)`.

Comment: I've tried ```typeid(component)``` but not ```*component```, will try now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `typeid(*component)`to get the dynamic type of the pointed-to object, not the declared type of its typename or of the pointer-to-it.

Naturally, `typeid(T)` will always be `T`. So, if you pass a less-derived type of pointer `T* component`, then `typeid(T)` is not equivalent to `typeid(*component)`.

Also, if you were trying `typeid(component)`, without dereferencing, then you should get the type of the pointer, not the type of what it points to, which shouldn't be correct.

Finally, although this seems already assured in your case, it's worth noting that the objects need to be polymorphic for this to work, i.e. to have at least one virtual member function. Otherwise, the RTTI that this needs won't exist.